# Backup Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I try to make Backup for database in SQL Server this error appear:

```
Backup failed for Server 'DESKTOP-100BUA8'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)



System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The volume on the device 
"E:\Special\Business\Dendistry\DB\DentistryBackupDB.bak" is not part of the media set that is 
currently being processed. Ensure that the backup devices are loaded with the correct media. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Backup error - not part of a multiple family media set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808115/sql-server-backup-error-not-part-of-a-multiple-family-media-set)

Comment: Does the `E:\Special\Business\Dendistry\DB` path exist on the SQL Server instance itself (as opposed to on your own computer)? Does the account under which the SQL Server service executes have at least Modify access (preferably Full Control access) to that path?

Comment: The path not exist on the SQL Server instance itself, But the account under which the SQL Server service executes have full control to that path

Comment: The backup command is executed by the database engine, so the path need to exist on the server and the service account for SQL Server need permissions on that path. I would have expected a different error message if the path wasn't available to the database engine, however. Pls start by checking the path and take it from there.

Comment: Is there a typo in the path d<->t ?